# jQuery .focus() not firing on each form element

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has multiple `<input>` fields.  I want to run a javascript function when each one is "engaged" so jQuery's `.focus()` seems to be the way to do this.

Running...

```
$('input').focus(change_submit_button_state(form_id, form_elements_id_array));
```

only runs the `change_submit_button_state` function once though.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an anonymous function if you want to pass arguments

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    change_submit_button_state(form_id, form_elements_id_array);
});
```

Or if you don't need the arguments

```
$('input').focus(change_submit_button_state);
```

When you add parentheses after a function, you call it and return the result, so what you're doing is more like

```
var x = change_submit_button_state(form_id, form_elements_id_array); 
//        ^ probably returns "undefined", unless you've specified someting else

$('input').focus(x); // still undefined
```